# Which of these is correct: "Is supposedly" or "supposedly is"?

Tags: adverbs, word-order

- "Something supposedly is true."
- "Something is supposedly true."

Are both of these correct English? Is there any notable difference in their meanings?

Comment: They're both valid, and mean the same - but *on average* we put the adverbial element immediately *after* the verb (***is***, here). Check out [this usage chart](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=that+is+really+true%2Cthat+really+is+true&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) (looking at ***really*** rather than ***supposedly***, but syntactically it's the same thing).

Comment: The general rule (from which there are many variations, but you're asking a general question) is that adverbs go after the first auxiliary verb in the verb phrase.

Comment: The placement of the adverb depends on whether it's modifying the verb or the adjective. But when the verb phrase is a form of "be <adjective>", there's not usually much difference and we usually put it before the adjective.